# Swift4, Firebase - Retrieve only value of key and put in array

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, key-value

I want to retrieve all the values of 'itemname' from Firebase and put them in my array generatedObjects. Now it seems like i get the parent, and also the key and value of its children, when i only want all values of 'itemname' ('Toiletry bag', 'Toothbrush' etc.). Not sure where to go from here, appreciate any help:

[image]

[image]

My code:

```
self.ref.child("lists").child("-LOXr5PoUvBn_tGNhql-").child(whatList!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let children = snapshot.children
            while let rest = children.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot{
                print(rest.value)
                //self.generatedObjects.append(rest.value as! [String: AnyObject])
            }

        },withCancel: nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
func getData() {
   ref.child("lists").child("-LOXr5PoUvBn_tGNhql-").child("mylist").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        let result = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]

        let item = result!["itemname"]
        //append item to your array
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func fetchdata(toId: String)
{
    Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(toId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] else {return}
        let itemname = dictionary["itemname"] as! String

        print(itemname)

    }
}
```

does it helpfull!!